# Определить какая версия jQuery на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли как-нибудь определить через консоль разработчка браузера какая версия установлена на сайте? В частностни, насколько знаю, от версии зависит возможность использования сокращений типа знака доллара ($). Если более старая версия, то нельзя, с новой уже работает. Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: посмотреть в подключенном файле

Answer (score 3):

Ответ можно найти за несколько секунд:

```js
var msg;
if (window.jQuery) {
    msg = 'You are running jQuery version: ' + jQuery.fn.jquery;
} else {
    msg = 'jQuery is not installed';
}
alert(msg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а где посмотреть версии, с которой знак доллара начинает работать?

Comment: @Mr.Robot Каr вариант, можно после того как определили что jquery присутствует сделать так же проверку, что $ объявлен. if( typeof $ == "function") { /* your code */}